# How can I activate a Python venv automatically when I ssh into a vagrant box?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, vagrant, python-venv

In a Vagrant VM running Ubuntu 16.04, I've created a Python 3 virtual environment using:

```
python3 -m venv /home/vagrant/venv
```

When I `vagrant ssh`, I can activate it using either:

```
source /home/vagrant/venv/bin/activate
```

or

```
. /home/vagrant/venv/bin/activate
```

During provisioning, I'm creating file `/etc/profile.d/login-bash.sh`:

```
cd /vagrant
. /home/vagrant/venv/bin/activate
```

When I `ssh` in, that file is running because I'm starting in the `/vagrant` shared directory, but that second line doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: The shell you are running when you ssh to the server is not the same as the one that is used during provisioning.

Are you sure that the venv isn't activated?

Comment: That's why I'm creating the file in `/etc/profile.d/` - I think files in this directory run at login? I know this much works, as the first line runs as expected

Comment: If you are already using a virtual machine, why not skip the virtual environment and configure the Python installation of the VM as needed?

Comment: I prefer to keep the project Python isolated from the OS

Comment: Maybe there are other scripts in profile.d that gets read after `login-bash.sh` which overwrites the path set by your venv?

Comment: @cyber-cap is there a way to find out what scripts run on login?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure how it works but all scripts in the directory `/etc/profile.d` are run.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `echo` command? Put one `echo` before sourcing, put one after, put one or two inside the `activate` script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. `~/.profile` will be run on each ssh login:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: 'echo ". /home/vagrant/venv/bin/activate" > ~/.profile', privileged: false
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem will be solved if you use the line below in your **Vagrantfile**:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: 'echo ". /home/vagrant/venv/bin/activate" > ~/.profile', privileged: false
```

If you need to activate your python enviroment and change directory to /vagrant use the line below in your **Vagrantfile**:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: 'echo ". /home/vagrant/venv/bin/activate && cd /vagrant" > ~/.profile', privileged: false
```

At the end of the day your **Vagrantfile** should look like (plus your own configurations):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|    
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: 'echo ". /home/vagrant/venv/bin/activate && cd /vagrant" > ~/.profile', privileged: false
end
```

Don't forget to run on the terminal `vagrant up --provision` to make your changes count after salve **Vagrantfile**